# Dock/Anchor alternative in C++ for List Control

Tags: winapi

In .NET there are Anchor & Dock properties that can make the controls responsive whenever you resize the window.

I want to do something similar with this C++ List Control. Basically I want to dock it in the dialog, so when I resize the window, it should be resizing.

[image]

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

#include <CommCtrl.h> // LV_COLUMN and ListView_x

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t c0_txt[] = L"Dogzu";
    
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        LVCOLUMNW col;
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 60;
        col.pszText = c0_txt;

        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, &col);

        return TRUE;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);
    
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 169
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,21,25,268,123
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MAIN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no docking support in the Windows API. You'll have to implement it manually by handling the [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) message:

```cpp
case WM_SIZE: {
    UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
    UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);

    // IDC_LIST1 will occupy the entire client area of its parent.
    // Adjust as needed.
    MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1),
        0, 0, width, height, TRUE);

    return TRUE;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, but when I start the application, the window is not like that at its default. How can I apply that from the start?

Comment: When the dialog is created the system picks up the sizes and positions of controls from the `DIALOGEX` resource. If you want a control to fill the entire client area from the start you can set the appropriate values in the resource script.

Comment: That's weird. Isn't there a better way with an API call which would update the control?

Comment: Not sure what's weird about the system using the values you provide. Though if you want to move/size controls prior to a dialog being displayed, `WM_INITDIALOG` is the place to do so.