# ListView's resizing takes the whole space, even the one provided for a status bar

Tags: c++, winapi

The UI consists of a menu, a list view and a status bar. My goal is to make it responsive and resize properly.

The following line of code: `MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, 0, width, height, TRUE);` basically takes the whole space, even the one provided for the status bar and whenever you resize the window, the ListView takes the entire space of the application. How can I make the ListView resizing respect the status bar?

#### Expected

[image]

#### Actual

[image]

```
// Enable Visual Styles
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

// Set Windows GUI Subsystem
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

// Required for LV_COLUMN and ListView_x
#include <CommCtrl.h>

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
    
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // Load icon
        const auto icon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 64, 64, 0));
        SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(icon));

        // Load menu
        HMENU hMenu = LoadMenuW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1));
        SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
            
        // Add ListView columns
        LVCOLUMNW col{};
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 60;
        wchar_t c0_txt[] = L"Title";
        col.pszText = c0_txt;
        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, &col);

        // Add Status Bar
        HWND hStatus = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd,
            reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(IDC_STATUS_BAR), GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), nullptr);

        int status_parts[] = { 100, 160, 300 ,-1 };
            
        SendMessageW(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&status_parts));
        SendMessageW(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(L"Test"));
            
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        SendMessageW(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATUS_BAR), WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
            
        const int width = LOWORD(lParam);
        const int height = HIWORD(lParam);

        MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, 0, width, height, TRUE);
        
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return FALSE; // we didn't handle that particular `msg` completely, therefore we should return FALSE. It can also depend on `wParam` and `lParam`.
    }
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 448
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 213
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 455, 220
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,21,25,396,160
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MAIN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDR_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Exit",                        ID_CONTROLPANEL_EXIT
    END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Folder.ico"

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDD_MAIN                        103
#define IDR_MENU1                       105
#define IDI_ICON1                       108
#define IDC_LIST1                       1009
#define ID_CONTROLPANEL_EXIT            40001
#define IDC_STATUS_BAR                  101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        109
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40002
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1010
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

## Edit:

Based on what @IInjectable said:

```
void LayoutControls(HWND hDlg, WPARAM wParam, int width, int height)
{
    SendMessageW(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_BAR), WM_SIZE, wParam, 0);

    // Calculate new client rectangle
    auto const client_rect{ RECT { 0, 0, width, height } };

    // Find the area occupied by the status bar
    auto sb_rect{ RECT {} };
    GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_BAR), &sb_rect);
    // Translate from screen coordinates to client coordinates
    MapWindowPoints(nullptr, hDlg, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&sb_rect), 2);

    // Calculate the remaining area
    auto remaining{ RECT {} };
    SubtractRect(&remaining, &client_rect, &sb_rect);

    // Optionally make room for a margin
    InflateRect(&remaining, -8, -8);

    // Resize control
    auto const x{ remaining.left };
    auto const y{ remaining.top };
    auto const width_x{ remaining.right - remaining.left };
    auto const height_y{ remaining.bottom - remaining.top };
    MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1), x, y, width_x, height_y, TRUE);
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
    
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // Load icon
        const auto icon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 64, 64, 0));
        SendMessageW(hDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(icon));

        // Load menu
        HMENU hMenu = LoadMenuW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1));
        SetMenu(hDlg, hMenu);
            
        // Add ListView columns
        LVCOLUMNW col{};
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 60;
        wchar_t c0_txt[] = L"Title";
        col.pszText = c0_txt;
        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1), 0, &col);

        // Add Status Bar
        HWND hStatus = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hDlg,
            reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(IDC_STATUS_BAR), GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), nullptr);

        int status_parts[] = { 100, 160, 300 ,-1 };
            
        SendMessageW(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&status_parts));
        SendMessageW(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(L"Test"));

        auto cr{ RECT{} };
        GetClientRect(hDlg, &cr);
        LayoutControls(hDlg, wParam, cr.right, cr.bottom);
            
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        // The other way below makes an assumption that there will be more controls in future.
        //RECT rc{};
        //GetClientRect(hDlg, &rc);

        //MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1), 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom - 25, TRUE);
        //MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_BAR), 0, rc.bottom - 20, rc.right, 20, TRUE);

        LayoutControls(hDlg, wParam, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));

        return FALSE;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hDlg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return FALSE; // we didn't handle that particular `msg` completely, therefore we should return FALSE. It can also depend on `wParam` and `lParam`.
    }
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [no automatic dialog layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68063446/1889329) in Windows' native windowing component. Any sort of dynamic dialog layout is to be performed manually.

Nothing complex involved here, you just need to calculate the positions as desired. Given your current setup you will have to find out the status bar control's area (after it has been moved/resized), and subtract it from the dialog's client area:

```cpp
case WM_SIZE: {
    SendMessageW(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATUS_BAR), WM_SIZE, wParam, 0);

    // Calculate new client rectangle
    auto const client_rect { RECT { 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) } };

    // Find the area occupied by the status bar
    auto sb_rect { RECT {} };
    GetWindowRect(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATUS_BAR), &sb_rect);
    // Translate from screen coordinates to client coordinates
    MapWindowPoints(nullptr, hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&sb_rect), 2);

    // Calculate the remaining area
    auto remaining { RECT {} };
    SubtractRect(&remaining, &client_rect, &sb_rect);

    // Optionally make room for a margin
    // InflateRect(&remaining, -8, -8);

    // Resize control
    auto const x{ remaining.left };
    auto const y{ remaining.top };
    auto const width{ remaining.right - remaining.left };
    auto const height{ remaining.bottom - remaining.top };
    MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), x, y, width, height, TRUE);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What about https://pastebin.com/np6V5rFc way? I like the margin from your way.  Btw for some reason yours don't respect the bottom margin until you resize the window a bit. Here is what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/sgqLqV6. Any way to fix it?

Comment: `RECT rc{}; GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc); MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom - 25, TRUE);  MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATUS_BAR), 0, rc.bottom - 20, rc.right, 20, TRUE);` this is the code from the pastebin.

Comment: A `WM_SIZE` message is generated in response to a window getting resized. Since there isn't when the dialog is initially created, the layout code in the `WM_SIZE` handler isn't executed. If you need to layout controls, you're either going to have to do that when handling `WM_INITDIALOG`, or force the system into generating a `WM_SIZE` message from there.

Comment: How do I force the system into generating WM_SIZE?

Comment: The code presented here is more general than it strictly needs to be. It was written under the assumption, that there will be other controls in the future that would need to be repositioned as well. If you don't need that you can just query for the status controls height (`GetWindowRect`), and subtract it from the bottom of the client area. No coordinate space translations required, no `SubtractRect` call either.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would stick to yours because it's reusable. I just need to figure out the issue with the margins - the system forcing thing

Comment: The most straight forward way would be to capture the layout logic into its own function, something like `void LayoutControls(HWND hDlg, int width, int height)`, and call that from `WM_INITDIALOG` and `WM_SIZE`. Contrary to my previous suggestion, forcing a `WM_SIZE` message doesn't appear to be possible without ramifications.

Comment: I moved your code into `void LayoutControls(HWND hDlg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` and called it from `WM_INITDIALOG` and `WM_SIZE`, but the ListView is now missing at application startup https://i.imgur.com/D4C958h.png

Comment: That's (presumably) passing the `wParam` and `lParam` values into the function. Those values have wildly different meanings for the `WM_INITDIALOG` and `WM_SIZE` message. `lParam` is 0 for the former, which is subsequently interpreted as the new window width and height, both evaluate to 0. A window with a width or height of 0 is invisible. My proposed function signature has `width` and `height` parameters for this reason.

Comment: how to get width and height out of wParam and lParam. Would you be able to write that function in the answer?

Comment: The width and height aren't available through `WM_INITDIALOG`'s arguments. You will have to call `GetClientRect` instead.

Comment: Can you please add that function into the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be useful. It's a trivial transliteration of the code provided.

Comment: I just want to make it look like the resizing version at application start.

Comment: Just move the code into a function with the signature I proposed above. When called from `WM_SIZE` pass in `LOWORD(lParam)` and `HIWORD(lParam)` for `width` and `height`. When handling `WM_INITDIALOG` just do `auto cr{ RECT{} }; GetClientRect(hWnd, &cr);` and pass `cr.right` and `cr.bottom` instead (`cr.left` and `cr.top` are always 0, no calculations required). Let me know how things pan out with this information.

Comment: What about `wParam`? `SendMessageW(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_BAR), WM_SIZE, wParam, 0);`

Comment: I updated the question. Did you mean that? I'm quite sure about `wParam`. May I leave it 0 all the time?

Comment: The `wParam` passed to `WM_SIZE` is meaningful to top-level windows only. Passing `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` to a status bar control doesn't make sense, for example. Plus, you're passing the `wParam` passed to `WM_INITDIALOG` into `LayoutControls`, but it has a [vastly different meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog). Just remove that parameter and send a `WM_SIZE` message to the status bar control with `wParam` set to zero.